# Apple Game Center - Sharing Data between 2 SKUs possible or not?

Tags: iphone, ipad, game-center

Question: Is it possible to access the same leaderboards and achievements via GC from 2 versions of a game (i.e. 2 different SKUs, one for iPhone/iPod and another for iPad. Where both are actually the same game in terms of game modes and features. For instance to be able to have different pricing)

Or: is this impossible and there is no other way than having 2 separate Leaderboards, Achievements -or- one universal binary.

Thanks in advance

*edit: typo and added remark about universal binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I'm just guessing here, but I'm pretty sure all the Game Center stuff is per app ID.  So if you have a regular and an HD version that use two different app IDs, you're probably SOL.  You'd more than likely have to make it a universal binary if you want your iPad and iPhone users competing.

Comment: Thats my guess, too. But i need to be as sure as i can. If anybody knows for sure i'd appreciate a comment about it. Cheers.

Comment: Whats the policy about crossposting. i.e. asking this same question on Stack Overflow, too. I've seen questions there about GC, too. Would not want to miss the knowledge of ppl over there who dont look here. Any suggestion?

Comment: @robo Do whatever you want.  If you get an answer over there that works be sure to bring it over here and mark it as accepted, though.

Comment: I found the following related questions at SO about this. a) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069148/one-game-center-account-for-two-ios-apps and with a slightly different angle b) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018028/game-center-api-in-app-purchases-api-two-different-user-accounts-for-a-single So i believe the answer is: It is not possible. If i find out otherwise during the production of our current title I will (hopefully remember to) update here.